# Can one specify a named docker volume to mount when creating a container? in the Json API

Tags: docker

The doc example only says

```
"Volumes" : {  "/internal/mount/point" : {} }
```

where the {} is I assume the default value.

With this a new Volume is created and assigned to the mount point when the container is started.

Is it possible to specify the name of a Volume that will be mounted or created at container create time?  Or specify the name at container start time? Using the Json remote API?

Answer (score 0):

I have found: this entry under the

```
HostConfig : {
    "Binds" : [ "test.data:/testvolume" ]
     ...
}
```

Will create a volume if it does not exist and mount it if it does exist when the container is started.

It looks like the "Mounts" item is potentially redundant though more detailed and has the same specs that one can provide in `"docker volume create"`.